# Run time error 13 Type mismatch

Tags: macros, vb, excel-2010

Tengo un problema con una macro que estoy intentando hacer. Debe buscar un rango de valores que le doy en todas las hojas del excel y debe devolver el nombre de las hojas en las que aparece cada valor del rango. el error se produce al compilar devolviendo

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

```
Sub findRecurrence()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As Range
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim rngFound As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xAddress As String

    xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set strSearch = Application.InputBox("Lookup values :", "Kutools for Excel", xAddress, Type:=8)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set rngSearch = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strSearch)
        If Not rngSearch Is Nothing Then
            i = i + 1
            If i = 1 Then
                rngFound = rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
            Else
                rngFound = rngFound & ", " & rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    MsgBox "'" & strSearch & "' found on the following worksheet(s): " & rngFound & "."
    End Sub
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Qué quieres decir con: *Debe buscar un rango de valores que le doy en todas las hojas del excel y debe devolver el nombre de las hojas en las que aparece cada valor del rango*. **¿Quieres decir que del rango que le das, debe buscar en todas las hojas esos mismos valores, por ejemplo nombres, y si encuentra alguno mostrar la hoja en la que se ha encontrado?**

Answer (score 0):

El error seguramente ocurre cuando seleccionas una rango mayor a una celda. Lo que ocurre es lo siguiente:

1. Estas accediendo directamente al objeto `strSearch` que es un `Range` y no un `String`, por defecto los objetos, cuando se accede a estos y no a alguna de sus propiedades, suelen tener una representación tipo cadena, pero es una mala práctica usarlos de esta forma por que no tenemos seguridad que siempre tendrá un valor. En tu ejemplo, cuando el rango elegido es de una sola celda no hay problema, el valor es el texto contenido en la misma, el problema ocurre cuando el rango aplica a varias celdas. La solución es acceder a la propiedad `strSearch.Text`, esta propiedad, si el objeto es válido siempre nos devolverá una cadena, la del valor de la celda o blanco (`""`) si el rango es de más de una celda.
2. Con lo que te comento anteriormente, únicamente deberíamos tener una lógica para que sea más claro el mensaje cuando el rango es mayor a una celda. Por ejemplo te sugiero lo siguiente:

   ```
   MsgBox "'" & IIf(strSearch.Text <> "", strSearch.Text, "Content of range: " & strSearch.Address) & "' found on the following worksheet(s): " & rngFound & "."
   ```

   Como puedes ver, mediante `IIf()` verificamos si `strSearch.Text <> ""` en cuyo caso el rango es de una sola celda y podemos usar `strSearch.Text` para mostrar el contenido buscado, en caso contrario, como el rango es mayor y no podemos mostrara todo el contenido, al menos informamos el rango mediante `strSearch.Address`